# bing video implementation

Tags: video, bing

I just see the [bing Video](http://www.bing.com/?scope=video) search , it is very good looking,

I am planning to make some thing like that,

I have different source of video (like Youtube, uploded video etc)

I just want to implement the "mouse hover" video play and pause functionality.

how can I implement that, any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you need to clarify a bit. What is your actual question? How the "play on hover" functionality works? If that is your question I can tell you right now that all the videos are flash movies, so the pausing and playing is done by Flash. Quite simple really :)

Comment: OK, I think on BING video search , first it display a image and when we put a mouse on that image , it starts to play the actual video and again when mouse is moved out from the video it display the image again , - this thing i want to archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done through Flash. Each "video" listed is a Flash movie showing a static image, when you move the mouse over it an event handler in the Flash script fires and starts playing a snippet. When it detects a "mouse out" it stops playing the movie.

So you'll need to do something similar. A Flash movie that accepts a URL to an arbitrary movie file some where on the internet. The Flash movie would load a bit of that movie and show the first frame when the movie's been loaded. When a mouse over is detected you play the loaded snippet, and on mouse out you stop playback.

The URL would be something that your search engine provide.

I'm sure you can do the same with Silverlight if that is your preferred toolkit.

Comment: thanks , But I have some Youtube video URL's also.
how to play those youtube video's in my flash player?